# How to remove item space between 2 pivot items in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-8, flipview

I am using pivot control to display full sizes multiple image on the screen as a flip view. But the problem with pivot is that it is taking empty space between two pivot items. How to eliminate this space?

If any other solution is available to display images as Flip view,please share.

I used FlipView control by Kinnara fork's as a datatemplate of ListBox:

```
<ListBox Background="AntiqueWhite" x:Name="FlipViewList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}"/>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
        <Grid Height="200">
            <toolkit:FlipView x:Name="ImagePivot" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding imageCollection}" Tag="{Binding}" IsLocked="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                <toolkit:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Width="480">
                            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding images}" Height="200" Width="480"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:FlipView>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Everything works fine but the vertical scrool is not working for listbox. How to resolve this scrool issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is there's no `FlipView` provided by `msdn` for the `WP8` platform where as it's been added to the 8.1 version:

[How to add a flip view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150601.aspx)

There are two options or even could be more, but i'm mentioning here two of them:

1) You could try out the `Telerik SlideView`  [control](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radslideview-gettingstarted.html):

[WinRT FlipView like control in WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647331/)

Sample has been given [here](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/flipview-for-windows-phone).

2) Or else you could go for the `FlipView` provided by [Kinnara's fork](https://github.com/Kinnara/WPToolkit).

Comment: I had tried FlipView by kinnara's fork. I used this as a child in Listbox so the problem is, this flipview is stopping the vertical scroll for listbox

Comment: What about the other one?

Comment: It seems to be Telerik SlideView control is paid one

Comment: You could go for the trial one still! http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/download.aspx

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i dont want to go for paid controls. Can you tell me that either we can remove the space which is shown in between 2 pivot items or can we give full width image as a panaroma item

Comment: You can give the width as `auto` and see, but it changes according to the resolution of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I decided to use my own custom XAML control. Basically, you can have a StackPanel that holds the images, and house that StackPanel within a Horizontally Scrolling ScrollViewer, and can modify the scrolling so that it scrolls 1 item at a time. the Images can be given a margin before adding them to the StackPanel, and that's how you can achieve the spacing between them. Check this out for instructions and a sample - https://quirkd.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/make-your-own-swipe-carousel-control/

Comment: I go through the link which has mentioned by you. But the issue is that, if i disable the horizontal scrolling in xaml then i am unable to set horizontal offset for a scrollviewer programatically as its horizontal scrolling is already disabled in xaml.